# Pseudo code to be spread over multiple pages?

Tags: floats, page-breaking, pseudocode

I am writing pseudo code in the algorithmic environment. It is quite long and doesn't fit on one single page. Instead of it continuing on the next page, it is cut off. I tried inserting it into a figure environment, but the problem persists. Is there a solution to have the code continue on the next page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you do not want the algorithm to float, just use the `algorithmic` environment without the `algorithm` environment.

Otherwise, you can use the [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package. It allows breaking long algorithms in parts, preserving line numbers and indentation. You can also combine this with [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)'s `\ContinuedFloat` to get proper algorithm numbering:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$

        \algstore{myalg}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\clearpage

\begin{algorithm}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \caption{My algorithm (continued)}
  \begin{algorithmic}
      \algrestore{myalg}

        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

*(The algorithm example is taken from `algorithmicx`'s documentation.)*

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot get this example to complie exactly as it is or even with modifications. ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.12       \State
                  $r\gets a\bmod b$

Comment: @Vass: Disregard my earlier comment. Which versions of `algorithm`, `algorithmicx` and `caption` do you have (see the log file)?

Comment: Here is what is said in the log file for the EXACT code place above for these keywords. Package: algorithmicx 2005/04/27 v1.2 Algorithmicx Document Style algorithmicx 1.2 - a greatly improved `algorithmic' style; Document style option `algorithm' Release 2.5 -- March 13 1995 --;Package: caption 2007/01/07 v3.0k Customising captions (AR). Thanks

Comment: @Vass: March 13 1995 is obviously _very_ old, and I suspect it is the cause. Update your TeX distribution or just [this package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) to a more reasonable version.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov: is it possible to let TeX do the algorithm breaking automatically?

Comment: @Stan: I believe that TeX will do it if you use `algorithmic` without `algorithm`. But then you need to do something about caption (perhaps `\captionof`).