# Code over two Pages and continue counting Lines

Tags: page-breaking, minted, line-numbering

I'm using Minted to show my Javascript Code. It seems not possible to spread a code with Minted over two pages.

So i do it like shown in [Algorithm over two pages, with itemized lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35674/algorithm-over-two-pages-with-itemized-lists). But the Code reset the line counting. They use : `\algstore{myalg}` and `\algrestore{myalg}` for Algorithms. is there a same instructions to saving counting for Minted?

**Code :**

```
\documentclass{article}
% define the program :
\newfloat{program}{tbp}{lop}}%
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{javascript}{bgcolor=lightgray,linenos=true,fontfamily=courier,fontsize=\footnotesize,frame=single}

\begin{document}
\begin{program}[H]
\begin{javascriptcode}
 \\Code Part 1
\end{javascriptcode}
\caption{Same Caption}
\label{prog:samelabel}
\end{program}

\newpage

\begin{program}[H]
 \ContinuedFloat
\begin{javascriptcode}
 \\Code Part 2
\end{javascriptcode}
\caption{Same Caption}
\label{prog:samelabel}
\end{program}
\end{document}
```

**Overview First Page**

```
1 <html>
2  <body> 
3   <script type="text/javascript">
4      document.write("Ich bin ein Javascript Code!");
```

**Program 1.2 Same Caption**

**Overview Second Page**

```
1   </script> 
2  </body>
3 </html>
```

**Program 1.2 Same Caption**

That the caption are the same is ok, but the numbering is resetting on the next page.

**Edit 1:**

In the Minted and Fancyvrb Documentation i see an Option : `[firstnumber=last]` that means that the numbering is continued from the previous Float.

How can i use it here? i tried :

```
\begin{program}[H]
 \ContinuedFloat
\begin{javascriptcode}[firstnumber=last]
```

but this dont do the Trick.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks! To make it an actual MWE, please add a document class and all necessary packages (but only necessary ones!), as it'll say in the link I posted. You might need to add filler text (German _Blindtext_) to get the code to break over two pages. I recommend either the package `lipsum` or the package `blindtext` for that.

Comment: see here for a solution using the `mdframed` package: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84291/8666

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to resolve it :

```
\begin{program}[H]
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=lightgray,linenos=true,fontfamily=courier,fontsize=\footnotesize,frame=single]{javascript}
 \\Code Part 1 : numbers going from 1..28
\end{minted}
\caption{Same Caption}
\label{prog:samelabel}
\end{program}

\newpage

\begin{program}[H]
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=lightgray,linenos=true,fontfamily=courier,fontsize=\footnotesize,frame=single,firstnumber=29]{javascript} 
 \\Code Part 2 change firstnumber value
\end{minted}
\caption{Same Caption}
\label{prog:samelabel}
\end{program}
```

Comment: You should use `firstnumber=last` to continue counting; see http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf#page=12.