# Too long algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I would like to know how it is to write a long algorithm beyond the edges of a page, knowing I used algorithm and algorithmic packages?

[image]

Comment: Either see [Algorithm over two pages, with itemized lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35674/5764) (breaking up the algorithm manually using `\algsave` and `\algrestore`) or [Algorithm tag and page break](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33866/5764) (automated break of algorithm that *doesn't float*). Give some feedback once you've visited these posts.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In my opinion, this is some Java code which implements an algorithm, but the various algorithm packages are designed to show language-independent pseudo-code features. It's better to use `listings` etc. for the representation of Java code

Comment: Isn't is more prudent to call this a source code (program) rather than algorithm?