# Algorithm pseudo code not published beyond one page

Tags: page-breaking, algorithms

My algorithm pseudo code is not being published beyond one page though there is no syntax error. The PDF  produced via LaTeX is of only one page but my entire algorithm requires more than one page. So only one page of my algorithm is published in PDF, rest of the matter is truncated. Why is there a limit of one page? Please suggest remedies.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{MyProcedure}{}
\State $\textit{stringlen} \gets \text{length of }\textit{string}$
\State $i \gets \textit{patlen}$
\BState \emph{top}:
\If {$i > \textit{stringlen}$} \Return false
\EndIf
\State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
\BState \emph{loop}:
\If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}
\State $j \gets j-1$.
\State $i \gets i-1$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
\State \textbf{close};
\EndIf
\State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
\State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
\BState \emph{loop}:
\If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}
\State $j \gets j-1$.
\State $i \gets i-1$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
\State \textbf{close};
\EndIf
\State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
\State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
\BState \emph{loop}:
\If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}
\State $j \gets j-1$.
\State $i \gets i-1$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
\State \textbf{close};
\EndIf
\State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
\State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
\BState \emph{loop}:
\If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}
\State $j \gets j-1$.
\State $i \gets i-1$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
\State \textbf{close};
\EndIf
\State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
\State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
\BState \emph{loop}:
\If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}
\State $j \gets j-1$.
\State $i \gets i-1$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
\State \textbf{close};
\EndIf
\State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
\State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
\BState \emph{loop}:
\If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}
\State $j \gets j-1$.
\State $i \gets i-1$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
\State \textbf{close};
\EndIf
\State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
\State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
\BState \emph{loop}:
\If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}
\State $j \gets j-1$.
\State $i \gets i-1$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
\State \textbf{close};
\EndIf
\State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: The pdf produced via latex is of only one page but my entire algorithm requires more than one page. So only one page of my algorithm is published in pdf, rest of the matter is truncated. Why is there a limit of one page?

Comment: @Werner Please refer to edits.

Comment: You either have to break it manually using `\algstore`...`\algrestore` (see [Algorithm over two pages, with itemized lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35674/5764)) or remove the floating capability and use something like a `breakablealgorithm` environment (see [Algorithm tag and page break](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33866/5764)). Either one should work for you, so give some feedback as to your preference.

Comment: @Werner I prefer much your answer for [Algorithm tag and page break](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33866/algorithm-tag-and-page-break). That was really cool. The other option is also geeky but you have to manually find the break points which is best avoided. thanks, had you put this comment in answer would have accepted it.

Comment: Since it is entirely solved by the linked post, we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Werner Right, that works for me.