# Split custom float over pages?

Tags: floats, page-breaking

I use a custom float `example`, but some of the code is running longer than a page.  Is there an easy way to split the float across pages?  The definition is as follows:

```
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{example}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{example}{Example}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: This is very similar to [Pseudo code to be spread over multiple pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14673/5764), only that you're using an `example` environment compared to `algorithm`. One possible solution would be to use `\ContinuedFloat`, as suggested in the [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14675/5764).